# Returning multiple elements in robot framework script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I'm having an issue with `Robot`.

I run this method within a python script and everything is ok.

```
go_button = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".xxx")[0]
```

Basically I need to grab the first element that matches this selector and I can do this no problem via python directly.

However, I cannnot do the same via `Robot`. I have something like this:

```
Click Button    css=.xxx
```

I guess my question is, how can I `index results` if a locator returns more than 1 result

Answer (score 1):

How about using `XPATH` locator as below to select the 1st element?

```
xpath=//*[@class='xxx'][1]
```